# Like with Regular Expression not giving right result in sql server

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008

```
declare @test varchar(50) 
    set @test='sad@fd'
    if @test LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9  ./,()?''+-]%'
    print 'yes'
    else
    print 'no'
```

My above code giving yes result as it should give no as I am not allowing '@' in regular expression. Is there anything wrong?

I want to handle this in my stored procedure where string is alpha numeric with specified list of special character allowed. What should I do?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 does not support regular expressions directly. You can use CLR...Here the Articale https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

Comment: if you just want to check for above example just do `if @test like %@%` ?

Answer (score 0):

The result is **"Yes"**, because u have an letter ***s*** which is matching the condition

to get more clear, try running the below code

```
declare @test varchar(1000) 
set @test='@@@@'
if @test LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9 ./,()?''+-]%'
    print 'yes'
    else
    print 'no'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to handle this in store procedure where string is aplha numeric with specified list of special character allowed.what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't really have native regular expressions<sup>1</sup>, but what you're trying to achieve can still be done with [`LIKE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) by introducing a double negative:

```
declare @test varchar(50) 
set @test='sad@fd'
if @test NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9  ./,()?''+-]%'
print 'yes'
else
print 'no'
```

`%` matches any number of characters. `^` inverts a character range. So, now we're asking - is the string *any* number of characters, then a character *not* in the set `a-zA-Z0-9  ./,()?''+-`, then *any* number of characters? - or, to put it another way, does this string contain any characters outside of the given set of characters?

---

<sup>1</sup>You can access a fully featured regex engine from the .NET framework by using the CLR integration. It's one of the usual samples given when talking about CLR integration. But not really needed here.